# How to boot and install Ubuntu on an AMD Athlon 200GE / Ryzen 2200G / 2400G

Tags: boot, system-installation, amd-graphics, amdgpu, amd-ryzen

When installing Ubuntu on a PC with an AMD APU like Athlon 200GE / Ryzen 2200G / Ryzen 2400G processor, the boot process doesn't complete and the screen remains black.

The OS won't boot after the live CD screen.

Comment: we only provide support for official Ubuntu releases. Any unofficial OS might work but please do not accept instructions on face value for those OS w/o confirming those will work on that OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Launch your kernel with "nomodeset" option:**

- During the boot process, press and hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key. Now you
  can see the grub menu.
- Press <kbd>e</kbd> key on first line to edit it.
- Go to line with the `quiet splash`sentence. Something like: `linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-xx-generic root=UUID=xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx ro quiet splash`.
- Add the `nomodeset` option between `ro` and `quiet splash`. You must 
  see someting like: `linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-xx-generic root=UUID=xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx ro nomedeset quiet splash`.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to boot the kernel.

-

**2. Proceed with the installation of your distro normally**

After the installation and reboot, if the screen remains black on the boot process, repeat the step 1, now editing the options for your installed Linux.

-

**3. Update your kernel to, at least, 4.19**

Download the .deb files below on this link: https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19/

```
linux-headers-4.19.0-xxxxxx_all.deb
linux-headers-4.19.0-xxx-generic(/lowlatency)_xxx_amd64(/i386).deb
linux-modules-4.19.0-xxx-generic(/lowlatency)_xxx_amd64(/i386).deb
linux-image-xxx-4.19.0-xxx-generic(/lowlatency)_xxx_amd64(/i386).deb
```

*Select **`generic`** for common system, and **`lowlatency`** for a low latency system (e.g. for recording audio), **`amd64`** for 64bit system, **`i386`** for 32bit system, or armhf, arm64, etc for other OS types.*

On the folder you downloaded the kernel **deb** files, open a terminal and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

-

**4. Restart your computer**

And you are done.

Comment: Done this on a MSI B450I ITX and an Athlon 200GE with success.