# How long should it take to install Ubuntu on a new hard drive?

Tags: system-installation

How long should it take for an installation on a new hard drive? No other operating system. Installing from a flash drive. I've been look at a screen with just the word UBUNTU on it for about an hour.

Comment: Maybe 20 minutes on average hardware.  Something gone wrong, should see it doing stuff.  If using an iso on dvd/usb the system should come up within 5min with desktop to let you decide to try it out or install.

Comment: Never more than 10 minutes here, start to finish. I never allow an internet connection during install so as to eliminate any slow down getting updates from a crappy Ubuntu server connection.

Comment: Does it have 5 dots under Ubuntu flashing on and off.  That should only be on less than a minute.

Comment: Tell us what you are using to install and what type of computer.

Comment: I'm attempting an install on new desktop components: Athlon 200, Asus A320 MB, 8 g ram and a 1T WD hard drive. Bios setup shows all components work properly. After clicking on install I did accidentally pulled the power cord out, This probably screwed it up. How I do a new install?

Comment: Can try this.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112316/how-to-boot-and-install-ubuntu-on-an-amd-athlon-200ge-ryzen-2200g-2400g/1112317

Comment: Did you verify your install-media is valid?  I usually validate my install-media before install, but if I have issues I re-do it anyway as the two minutes it takes to run saves hours-days of wrongly-directed trouble-shooting.

Comment: Which Ubuntu are you trying, might need 19.04 for that cpu.

Comment: We need more info added  --into the question--  not as a comment.

Comment: Sorry I let this hang with a reply. I actually had a hardware problem. I had to replace the MB.