# 18.04 - Unable to boot with Athlon 200GE and Ryzen APU after upgrading from 5.1.* to 5.2.* kernel

Tags: 18.04, kernel, amd-ryzen

To be able to use my **Athlon 200GE APU** on Ubuntu 18.04, I have to temporarily boot with `nomodeset` and update the kernel to, at least, **`4.19`** from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ *( instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112316/how-to-boot-and-install-ubuntu-on-an-amd-athlon-200ge-ryzen-2200g-2400g) )*.

Since then, I update the kernel with every non-rc mainline kernel release, and the experience is perfect.

Every kernel between **`4.19.*`** and **`5.1.*`** branches **works flawlessly**, but now, no kernel from branch `5.2.*` works (including `5.2`, `5.2.1` and `5.2.2`).

I am only able to boot with `5.2.*` **using `nomodeset` again**, but it seems that the APU isn't used on all its potential, since login screen only appears on one monitor *(there are two)* and with wrong resolution.

What changes were made on branch 5.2 that create this issue? And which options do we have as an user?

Comment: `5.1.xx` Linux Kernel chain will hit end of life soon. Because `5.2.xx` doesn't work you are best staying on `4.19.xxx` kernel chain which has 5 year lifespan (LTS). There might be problems with `4.19.60` though in which case use `4.19.59` until fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that graphics off functionality is not working properly (see [phoronix forum](https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/linux-graphics-x-org-drivers/open-source-amd-linux/1115604-kernel-5-2-compatiblity-with-athlon-200ge-and-ryzen-apus)). Usage of kernel parameter `amdgpu.ppfeaturemask=0xffff3fff` fixed the issue for me.